# Как проверить, инициализирована ли переменная?

Tags: java

Приложение получает значения для двух переменных из текстового файла построчно через BuferedReader в цикле while. Мне нужно использовать обе переменные, но если использовать их после цикла приложение не компилируется с ошибкой:

> Integer a - Program.main(String[])
> The local variable a may not have been initialized

Если сразу дать переменным какое либо значение, то приложение компилируется и работет как надо, но значения должны передаваться именно из файла. Я пробовал сразу сделать значения для переменных null, но в таком случае выходить ошибка:

> a = Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: a != java.lang.Integer
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4442)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2976)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2924)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689)
> at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
> at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
> at Program.main(Program.java:31)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    String formatException = "Неправильный формат, проверьте правильность строки в input.txt";
    String str;
    Integer a = null;
    Integer b = null;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] datas = str.split(" ");
        if(datas[0].equals("a")){
            try {
                a = Integer.valueOf(datas[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(formatException);
            }
        }
        else if(datas[0].equals("b")){
            try {
                b = Integer.valueOf(datas[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(formatException);
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(formatException);
        }
    }
    if(a != null && b != null){
        System.out.printf("a = %a, b = %b", a, b);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(formatException);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Значения в файле должны быть записаны в формате:

a число

b число

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема, чем вас null не устраивает? Вполне себе нормальное значение для неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: @РусланМамедов В коде, который я скинул я сделал null. Но он выдает ошибку, которая над кодом.

Comment: Проблема в спецификаторах формата. Должно быть `System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в строке

```
 System.out.printf("a = %a, b = %b", a, b);
```

Замените на:

```
System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
```

А использование null для неинициализированной переменной абсолютно правильный подход